# How to pass the value of select statement?

Tags: select, loops, count, sql-server-2008-r2

i have this line of code in SQL server 2008 R2

```
select * from [Db].[dbo].[cart] where date < DATEADD(MINUTE, -30, GETDATE())
```

i want count all data that satisfy the condition and passed to a variable like

```
Declare @loop
```

i will use the variable to know the loop count..

The question is: How can i passed the Value of Select statement to the @loop variable.

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
DECLARE @loop INT

select  @loop = COUNT(1) 
from    [Db].[dbo].[cart] 
where   date < DATEADD(MINUTE, -30, GETDATE())
```

Have a look at [SELECT @local_variable (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187330.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
 SELECT @loop = @@RowCount
```